# for OTP input field Enable the button only when all 6 digits are filled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an OTP form field that has a disabled 'confirm' button.
the button should be enabled only when all the 6 digits are filled.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="otp" class="flex form-otp text-center pb-3">
    <input class="text-center form-control" type="text" id="digit-1" name="digit-1" data-next="digit-2" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="text-center form-control" type="text" id="digit-2" name="digit-2" data-next="digit-3" data-previous="digit-1" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="text-center form-control" type="text" id="digit-3" name="digit-3" data-next="digit-4" data-previous="digit-2" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="text-center form-control" type="text" id="digit-4" name="digit-4" data-next="digit-5" data-previous="digit-3" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="text-center form-control" type="text" id="digit-5" name="digit-5" data-next="digit-6" data-previous="digit-4" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="text-center form-control" type="text" id="digit-6" name="digit-6" data-previous="digit-5" maxlength="1" />
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn js-otp-confirm disabled"> confirm </button>
```

I have tried this below JQuery code using **.is(':empty')** but it is not working... can someone guide me here what wrong I am doing.

```
$('.form-otp').find('input').each(function() {
    $(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
        var parent = $($(this).parent());
            if(e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37) {
                var prev = parent.find('input#' + $(this).data('previous'));
                if(prev.length) {
                    $(prev).select();
                }
            } else if((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) || e.keyCode === 39) {
                var next = parent.find('input#' + $(this).data('next'));
                if(next.length) {
                    $(next).select();
                }
            }
        if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
            $('.js-otp-confirm').addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $('.js-otp-confirm').removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the script that i had updated

```
$('.form-otp').find('input').each(function() {
    $(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
      var parent = $($(this).parent());
      if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37) {
        var prev = parent.find('input#' + $(this).data('previous'));
        if (prev.length) {
          $(prev).select();
        }
      } else if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) || e.keyCode === 39) {
        var next = parent.find('input#' + $(this).data('next'));
        if (next.length) {
          $(next).select();
        }
      }
      var counter = 0;
      $('.form-otp').find('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
          counter++;
        } else {

        }
      });

      if (counter > 0) {
        $('.js-otp-confirm').addClass('disabled');
      } else {
        $('.js-otp-confirm').removeClass('disabled');
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use each to validate.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $('.otp').change(function(){
  $('#otp input[type=text]').each(function(){
      if($(this).val().length !== 0) {
          count = count + 1;
       }
  });
  if(count === 21){
    $('#btn-active').removeClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#btn-active').addClass('disabled');
  }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="otp" class="flex form-otp text-center pb-3">
    <input class="text-center form-control otp" type="text" id="digit-1" name="digit-1" data-next="digit-2" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="text-center form-control otp" type="text" id="digit-2" name="digit-2" data-next="digit-3" data-previous="digit-1" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="text-center form-control otp" type="text" id="digit-3" name="digit-3" data-next="digit-4" data-previous="digit-2" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="text-center form-control otp" type="text" id="digit-4" name="digit-4" data-next="digit-5" data-previous="digit-3" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="text-center form-control otp" type="text" id="digit-5" name="digit-5" data-next="digit-6" data-previous="digit-4" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="text-center form-control otp" type="text" id="digit-6" name="digit-6" data-previous="digit-5" maxlength="1" />
</div>
<button type="submit" id="btn-active" class="btn js-otp-confirm disabled"> confirm </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with 1 line filter function.

```
   $('.muse-otp').find('input').each(function () {
    $(this).on('keyup', function (e) {
        var parent = $($(this).parent());
        if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37) {
            var prev = parent.find('input#' + $(this).data('previous'));
            if (prev.length) {
                $(prev).select();
            }
        } else if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) || e.keyCode === 39) {
            var next = parent.find('input#' + $(this).data('next'));
            if (next.length) {
                $(next).select();
            }
        }
        if ($('.muse-otp').find('input').filter(function () { return this.value === ''; }).length === 0) {
            $('.js-otp-confirm').removeClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $('.js-otp-confirm').addClass('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```